# enable JSDoc in SAP Web IDE

Tags: sapui5

I want to use JSDOC3 with the SAP WEBIDE. I see the point in the menue "Create JSDoc Comment" but it is disabled. I don't find any options to enable it. Do you guys have any clues?

Kind regards
Gaibler

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi4CD.png)

Comment: its sollved need to click on the keyword function

Comment: make sure that your file is not in error state

Answer (score 0):

Where you place the cursor matters to whether the "Generate JSDoc Comment" item in the context menu is enabled or not. Place the cursor between the string "function()" and try again. It should be enabled now.